# Python program for NIST randomness equation

Tags: python, math, equation

There is a recurrence equation on page 1789 of [this](http://dl.jbnu.ac.kr/dlsearch/dllocal/LOC/HTML/chonbuk/digital/IEICE/IEICE-TranFundElecCommandCompSci/ieice_ietfec_2007_e90-a-09/1788.pdf) paper and I need some help making a python program to calculate pi_i.  I have no idea what is going on here.

Other references:[original paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/SP800-22b.pdf), pages (according to adobe, not the physical pages) 43 and 86

edit and i had already deleted what i wrote because all the answers i got were 0, even though all the values were floats. i believe what i had looked somewhat like the code posted below

Comment: yeah, but im terrible at using it in programs

Comment: There was no reason to close this, he's asking for programming help for a specific equation.

Comment: In the last page of the paper there is the source code for the program. Its written in Mathematica, but is pretty straightforward to read. Be aware that the := sign means function declaration and the real execution are the last ten lines

Comment: @calccrypto: It's fine to ask for help when you're stuck with a problem, but you should *show your work*: let us know what you've tried and where you're stuck rather than just asking for someone to dig in and do it for you. If you're just having trouble understanding recursion, [there are plenty of existing answers on the topic...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recursion+python)

Comment: Links to references are great, but you need to put enough in the question that it still makes sense and is answerable once those links stop working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pseudocode/VBAish answer:

```
Function T(i as Integer, n as Integer, m as Integer) As Double

Dim j As Integer, temp As Double

Select Case i
    Case 0
        If n < 1 Then
            n = 1
        Else
            If n < m Then
                T = 2 * T(0,n-1)
            Else
                T = 2 * T(0,n-1) - T(0,n-m-1)
            End If
        End If
    Case 1
        If n < m Then
            T = 0
        Else
            If n = m Then
                T = 1
            Else
                If n = m + 1 Then
                    T = 2
                Else
                    temp = 0
                    For j = -1 to n-m-1
                        temp = temp + T(0,j) * T(0,n-m-2-j)
                    Next j
                    T = temp
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Case 2 to 9999999
        temp = 0
        For j = -1 to n-2*m-i
            temp = temp + T(0,j) * T(i-1,n-m-2-j)
        Next j
        T = T(i-1,n-1) + temp
End Case

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you will need to calculate the intermediate values as described in the paper, then loop on them to add them where you see the big summation signs...